# Project Euler #23 Incorrect Answer

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have just completed my solution for project euler problem number 23 which states:

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors
>   is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper
>   divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28
>   is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is
>   less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the
>   smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers
>   is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers
>   greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.
>   However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis
>   even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be
>   expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as
>   the sum of two abundant numbers.

This is my solution:

```
from math import sqrt
def divisors(n):
    for i in range(2, 1 + int(sqrt(n))):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
            yield n / i

def is_abundant(n):
    return 1 + sum(divisors(n)) > n

abundants = [x for x in range(1, 28123 + 1) if is_abundant(x)]
abundants_set = set(abundants)

def is_abundant_sum(n):
   for i in abundants:
       if i > n:  # assume "abundants" is ordered
         return False
       if (n - i) in abundants_set:
           return True
   return False

sum_of_non_abundants = sum(x for x in range(1, 28123 + 1) if not is_abundant_sum(x))
print(sum_of_non_abundants)
```

My answer is: 3906313

Explanation of my code:
The `divisors` **generator** pretty much returns all nontrivial divisors of an integer, but makes no guarantees on the order. It loops through 1 to square root of *n* and yields the divisor and its quotient. The next function `is_abundant` actually checks if sum of divisors of *n* is less than n then return False else return True. Next is the list `abundants` which holds all the abundant numbers from 1 to 28123 and `abundants_set` is just like `abundants` but instead it's a set not a list. The next function is `is_abundant_**sum**` which pretty much checks if the sum given to the functions is itself abundant or not and in the end the sum of numbers which are not `is_abundant_sum` is printed.

Where did I do wrong? What's the problem in my code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your problem is your divisors function

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what problem?

Comment: if you add the sums in your divisors function and return there and just call that, forget about the is_abundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `divisors` generator double counts the factor `f` of `f**2`. This bug affects the computed list of abundant numbers.

Comment: Didn't get it, can you elaborate?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui For example, `list(divisors(4))` evaluates to `[2, 2]`, causing `4` erroneously to be treated as abundant.

Comment: So should I half the numbers of divisors I get? :P

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: No; just don't count the square root of a square integer twice.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui The easiest fix is to yield `n / i` only if it's greater than `i`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you explain why?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Even after applying your fix I get `4179871` which is still incorrect. :/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You mean that I step the loop with i**2 ?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Since `i` is less than or equal to `sqrt(n)`, we know that `i**2 <= n` and thus that `i <= n/i`. Unless `i < n/i`, the second yield statement repeats the factor `i`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Even after applying your fix I get `4179871` which is still incorrect. :/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui That's the answer that I solved #23 with.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Sorry, I don't know why it didn't worked in the first place, but thanks, it worked now. :)